# View Hierarchy not prepared for constraint

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to make a tab system in my app such that when a UIButton is tapped, the view switches and a line moves from the other tab button to under the button that was just pressed, and the same for the other tab button. I am doing this by creating a UIView for the green line and two UIButton's for the tab buttons. Both the Buttons are hooked up to IBActions which remove a constraint that ties it's center.x to the old tab button's center.x and add a constraint that binds it to the new tab's button's center.x. However, the button needs to start aligned to the first tab, and when I try to add that constraint programmatically in viewDidLoad, it crashes with "View Hierarchy not prepared for constraint". I cannot add this initial constraint in IB because I need some way to remove it when the next button is pressed.
I will be happy to provide code or more details if needed.

Thank you

Comment: That crash usually just means that you tried to add the constraint before you added the views to which it refers.

Comment: "I cannot add this initial constraint in IB because I need some way to remove it when the next button is pressed" Not true. You _can_ add it in IB and remove it later. Why not? It's just a nib object like any other. Make an outlet to it and then you can easily reference it and remove it in code.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the outlet suggestion, but can I know when the view the outlet refers to is loaded?

Comment: I thought we were talking about an outlet to a constraint? Anyway, when your view controller's view has loaded, you get `viewDidLoad` and all its outlets come to life. Let me know if you need to know how nibs load and what an outlet is...

Comment: Thanks so much, the outlet suggestion worked out nicely

Comment: Cool-o-rama! Thanks for reporting back.